# Compute $\operatorname{cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i,\sum_{i=1}^{N}Y_i\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{4}$. Let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ be another sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{3}{4}$.Let $N$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $P(N=k)=\frac{1}{2^k}$ where $k=1,2,\ldots$. Assume the $X_i's,Y_j's$ and $N$ are all independent. Compute $\operatorname{cov}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}X_i,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}Y_i\right)$.

**My try:**

See that $\sum X_i\mid N=n \sim \mathsf{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{4})$ and $\sum Y_i\mid N=n \sim  \mathsf{Bin}(n,\frac{3}{4})$.

Now, by law of total expectation, $E\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{N} X_i\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)=\frac{3}{2}$.

But how can I find $E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} X_i \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)$?

Comment: Since $X_i$'s are iid random variables so we have $$\Bbb E \left (\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i \right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} \Bbb E (X_i) \Bbb E (Y_j).$$

Comment: Then how to calculate after that?

Comment: From my above comment it follows that $$\Bbb E \left (\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i \right ) = \Bbb E \left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} X_i \right ) \Bbb E \left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}Y_i \right ).$$ Now you know both $\Bbb E \left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} X_i \right )$ and $\Bbb E \left (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} Y_i \right).$

Comment: Then the covariance will be 0?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Your expression for expectations contains random variables in r.h.s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the same way, law of total expectation gives that 
$$\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)=\mathbb E\left(\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\biggm| N\right)\right)$$
Since given $N$ both sums are independent, one can write this expression as
$$
\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)=\mathbb E\left(\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \biggm | N\right) \cdot \mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\biggm| N\right)\right)
$$
Next use that given $N$, both sums has binomial distributions and get
$$
\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)=\mathbb E\left( \frac14N\cdot \frac34N\right)=\frac9{16}\mathbb E(N^2)=\frac{9}{16}\left(\text{Var}(N)+(\mathbb E(N))^2\right)=\frac{9}{8}.$$
Finally 
$$
\textrm{cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i, \sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i\right)=\frac{9}{8}-\frac12\cdot\frac32=\frac38.
$$

Comment: Nicely done  !!!!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).